# ReCaptcha Offline / Local Usage

Tags: javascript, localhost, offline, recaptcha

Can I download Google's reCaptcha JavaScript API and work with it completely offline?

If so, is there any additional dependencies that I need to download along with it? And lastly, how do I configure the main JavaScript API to point it to its dependencies?

Comment: I have to ask why you'd want to do this.  You'd lose a lot of the benefits of a 3rd party API (updates, bug fixes etc.) for very little (if any) benefit (most likely already cached if using the common API).  Plus any dependencies could be embedded in the code, so you'd have to modify it to not look where it currently does.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can. In order to verify the user's response you have to send data to Google's webservice, and get a response. All that verification business logic is on Google's servers. The same applies when you load the GUI - it's dyanmically generated by Google's server each time. There's no "free download" link for this stuff. It's proprietary software-as-a-service.  From Google's point of view its purpose is to drive users to their services - this particular one might not sell ads, but they use it to capture data for AI research, and it requires you to get an account with them

Comment: @Archer I am developing a system and have no internet connection wherever I go, thus I wanted to be able to use the captcha despite of this limitation when I develop. But I do not plan this to be inevitably offline as I am going to upload this to a server. I am only doing this offline stuff whenever I am still developing the system.

Comment: @ADyson Ohhh. I see. I was running in the assumption that the entire thing can work despite offline.Thank you for the insight! :)

Comment: @RinMinase perhaps develop your app with a flag (in your settings or wherever) so you can easily enable/disable captcha functionality - if you build the app in a suitable modular way, you can then choose whether or not to run the relevant bits of code (to render the captcha and check the response) based on the setting. Then when you are developing offline you can just switch the setting and carry on your other dev/testing work

Comment: Or use a wrapper interface with dependency injection and create a dummy captcha class which always returns true. That structure would also enable you to switch to another captcha system easily if google's service were to be removed or become unsuitable in future. It's a good structure to use in general when working with 3rd-party services or libraries.

Comment: ^^ All of the above.  Just turn it off for development.  You could do it with a config change so your dev and live environments "just work".